# SQL - Selecionar todos os registros com erros de codificação

Tags: sql, mysqli

Fazer um select no banco trazendo todos os registros com erros de codificação:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE titulo LIKE '%Ã‡Ãƒ%'
```

Alguém sabe outra forma mais eficiente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar dados que não estejam em `UTF-8` comparando os tamanhos:

```
SELECT * FROM suaTabela
WHERE LENGTH(suaColuna) != CHAR_LENGTH(suaColuna)
```

Isso retornara todas as linhas que tenham `multibyte`.
Segue a [fonte](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77101/how-to-find-non-utf8-data-in-mysql).